# How can I use the Process.Start() command with multiple parenthesis?

Tags: vb.net, process, cmd, parentheses

Basically, I'm trying to open cmd to execute a command that will modify my firewall. The only problem is that the line of code requires parenthesis and it doesn't work with the Process.Start()

Process.Start("cmd", "/c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="neter" new enable="no"")

I get the error "Error  2   Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected." on the parenthesis before neter.

Comment: Process.Start("cmd", "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=""neter"" new enable=""no""")

Answer (score 0):

It is the quotes that are the problem. Use "" for each single " in a string.

```
Process.Start("cmd", "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=""neter"" new enable=""no""")
```

There is no need to call `cmd`. Call `NetSh` direct.